# Switch back and forth between last two buffers in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like to switch back and forth between the last two visited buffers (current one and previous one) and bind the command to `M-b`.

`(switch-to-buffer (other-buffer))` in theory should accomplish this, but adding the following code to my `.emacs` has no effect.

```
(defun my-switch-to-other-buffer ()
  "Switch to other buffer"
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer (other-buffer)))

(global-set-key [M-b] 'my-switch-to-other-buffer)
```

Please suggest a fix to the code above or a better way to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks pretty well and seems to work in my emacs session.

Are you sure about the `[M-b]` syntax?

If this is the problem you probably want to use the `kbd` function instead to determinie the right way to spell the key combination.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-b") 'my-switch-to-other-buffer)
```

I always define my keybindings this way as I tend to forget how to correctly ?\C-#whatever get the name right.

Using `kbd` it's extremely simple, as it accepts a string having the same syntax as that echoed by `decribe-key` usually bound to `C-h C-k`.

This way I just have to type `C-h C-k` in case I don't know how the key is labeled and put the output of this command in my call to `kbd`. Especially in cases where it doesn't seem to obvious how to get it right `kbd` is extremely helpful it even works with more complex names `(kbd "<backtab>")` and the like.

Comment: Great, the `kbd` made it work. I incorrectly thought that `[...]` accepted the syntax echoed by `describe-key` as well.

Comment: Lex Fridman: the vector equivalent is `[?\M-b]` (see `C-h i g (elisp) Key Sequences RET`). `kbd` really is simpler, though.

Comment: @LexFridman @phils `[(meta b)]` works as well, and IMO it's the most readable key description format.  Although now-a-days I use `kbd` format.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, first of all avoid re-binding `M-b` as it's word backwards, and it'll be useful for you to maintain the default bindings, and learn them, so that you can use Emacs when your config isn't available, say on a remote box or some other unfamiliar site. (I know the chances of that are probably lessening these days.) The other, more pertinent reason is that it's the default key binding on `bash` / `readline` which is available in more places than I care to mention.

If you're on a windows box, I'd suggest binding the windows key to <kbd>hyper</kbd> or <kbd>super</kbd> so that you can get a whole extra range of key bindings without wiping out the defaults.

On a mac, do the same with <kbd>Cmd</kbd> (although it's already bound to <kbd>super</kbd>, and has a bunch of mac specific keys already bound.)

Finally, always remap <kbd>Caps-Lock</kbd> even if you don't use it for the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> replacement that a lot of people use, it's another modifier that you can repurpose and use more often in Emacs (really, there's never any need to use caps-lock when there's `M-l`, `M-u` and `M-c` available.) - once you've got <kbd>hyper</kbd> and <kbd>super</kbd> you've got easily another hundred bindings available as <kbd>modifier</kbd> + <kbd>key</kbd> style shortcuts.

Also, I know it's a massive hassle, but `C-x b` <kbd>enter</kbd> will switch to the previous buffer.

Comment: IMHO in modern times its rather the default emacs keybindings that are spoiling general workflow using external applications. Having used it for a too long period nonstop it's countless countless times I've open up 3 new files trying to move the cursor down (C-n) and opened opened up 4 print dialogs (C-p) before I really realize what's going on. Looking back I would have been happy if i had changed my emacs bindings early enough, now I'm stuck with them. Nevertheless +1 as breaking some of the most fundamental keybindings might not be the best idea.

Comment: @Solomojo Oh, and BTW I'm sure using hyper super and the like isn't too bad idea, but if you tend to use emacs in a terminal, like I do those bindings won't be available. It's even impossible to distinguish C-i from TAB and C-m from RET there, as both send ^I and ^M.

Comment: and here I was thinking my answer was for Lex.

Comment: Such as my first comment. But as you can see I'm never too tired to learn something new myself.

Comment: I'm pretty surprised you're only using Emacs in the terminal, I do myself too, but it's a fraction of my Emacs time.  Why aren't you using TRAMP or just version control and get yourself out of the hole. These days,  generally it's Emacs that runs my terminals, not the other way around.

Comment: By the way, readline (read Emacs) control keys are available in a LOT of software, all the text-controls (including in browser) in OS X for example offer a good subset of basic Emacs key bindings. (C-e, C-a are there for example, as are C-f C-b C-p C-n ... there's a few more (OS X does clobber M-b and M-f though)

Comment: I made a list of a few activities (4 to be exact) that I do over and over and over in Emacs when programming. And for those I decided to put convenience over any other consideration. [M-b] is the easiest shortcut for me. I'm using a Kinesis keyboard. So, I think your point is an excellent one about not interfering with basic Emacs keybindings. But sometimes I must follow the heart not the brain ;-)

Comment: @LexFridman cheers for the feedback, ultimately Emacs is meant to be what you want and need it to be, my answer should be heavily parenthesised in "if you prefer it this way" - I've been using Emacs on an off for a couple of decades, and the last 5 years or so, I've been undoing some habits and embracing the full power of the platform. One of those powerful things is the ubiquity of some of it's built in bindings across many other platforms. This is why I recommended using `hyper` & `super` bound to whatever to get you a lot more, bang for your buck, while keeping it consistent with defaults.

Answer (score 3):

BTW the above lisp code doesn't work (sometimes it brings you to another buffer different from the previous one). Emacs has a built-in function to perform this task: **mode-line-other-buffer**